# Aggregating two Pandas series by summing

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, sum, aggregate

I am trying to sum two series that have some matching indexes, but some that are unique.  e.g.:

```
a = pd.Series([0.2, 0.1, 0.3], index=['A', 'B', 'C'])
b = pd.Series([0.2, 0.2], index=['A', 'D'])
```

Notice that index A is in both a, and b.  I want to end up with a new series, which has the summed up aggregate of all indices:

```
A    0.4
B    0.1
C    0.3
D    0.2
dtype: float64
```

notice index A is the sum of both a and b (0.2 + 0.2), whereas B, C, and D are the original value.  If I try to do:

```
c = a + b
```

I get the proper value for index A, but NaN for all other values.  Any thoughts on the best way to do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
c = a.add(b, fill_value=0)
In [28]: c
Out[28]: 
A    0.4
B    0.1
C    0.3
D    0.2
dtype: float64
```

Use the .add method.

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.Series.add.html#pandas.Series.add

[Adding two pandas.series objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16202711/adding-two-pandas-series-objects)